# Compile PHP 5.5/5.6 and PHP-FFMPEG from source

Tags: php, wamp

I am using WAMP 2.4.9 on Windows 7. PHP version is 5.5.12. I downloaded the latest available version of PHP-FF-MPEG. I added the extension files as directed, but when I try to start the WAMP with instruction to load extension php-ffmpeg.dll in php.in, an error message shows up saying:

> PHPStartup: ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with
>   module API=20100525 PHP compile with module API=20121212 The options
>   need to match.

I searched the error and found that I must compile both the PHP and the extension causing such error from source code. I found an example for compiling php with php-profiler extension from source code. But it was a PECL extension. The directory structure and files are different in PHP-FFMPEG than that of PHP Profiler.

Please help me how can I compile PHP and PHP-FFMPEG? Note that I have successfully compiled PHP with PHP-UProfiler.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to install ffmpeg will create compatibility problems. So i would suggest you to install [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) windows build as standalone. After installing create [Environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for ffmpeg.

Then you can execute ffmpeg from php [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) method :

```
<?php exec("ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi") ?>
```

If you deploy your code in production environment on Linux then you can also install ffmpeg on linux as well. check ubuntu installation for ffmpeg [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-10-using-ppa.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it works for you then you can accept this as answer